# Chaining promises when using ES6 classes

Tags: google-app-engine, promise, ecmascript-6

I've the following code to upload a file to Google cloud and afterwards get the public URL. However, it quickly becomes messy when chaining the promises.

Could anyone help with a specific example of chaining the promises in a cleaner way in my example?

```
let routes = function(imageUploader) {
    router.post('/upload',
        imageUploader.getMulter().single('image'),
        (req, res) => {
            imageUploader.uploadFilePromise(req.file.path)
                .then((filename, error) => {
                    if(error) throw new Error(error);
                    imageUploader.getExternalUrl(filename)
                        .then((publicUrl, error) => {
                            if(error) throw new Error(error);
                            console.log(publicUrl);
                        })

                })
    });

    return router;
};
```

I included my ImageUploader class is here as well just as an FYI. Any other best practices suggestions are also much welcome.

```
const Multer = require('multer'), gcloudStorage = require('./vendors/gcloud');

class ImageUploader {

    constructor() {
        this.bucket = gcloudStorage;
    }

    uploadFile(req, res, next) {
        if(!req.file) {
            next();
        }

        this.bucket.upload(req.file.path, (err, file) => {
            if(err) throw new Error(err);
            req.file.publicUrl = this.getExternalUrl(req.file.name)
        })
    }

    uploadFilePromise(path) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.bucket.upload(path, (err, file) => {
                if(err) reject(err);
                resolve(file.name);
            })
        })
    }

    getExternalUrl(filename) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.bucket.file(filename).getSignedUrl({
                action: 'read',
                expires: '03-17-2025'
            }, (err, url) => {
                if (err) reject(err);
                resolve(url);
            });
        });
    }

    storage() {
        return Multer.diskStorage({
            destination: function (req, file, cb) {
                cb(null, 'uploads/')
            },
            filename: function (req, file, cb) {
                cb(null, Date.now() + file.originalname)
            }
        });
    }

    getMulter() {
        return require('multer')({ storage: this.storage() });
    }
}

module.exports = ImageUploader;
```

Comment: Not sure what is really ES6-specific about this question?  Yes, you're showing a `class` definition,but I'm not sure the question is any different with an object declared with ES6 syntax or the older ES5 way of creating an object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A callback passed to `then()` receives one and only one argument, not two.

And it can (should) return a value, or another promise, in order to allow further chaining.

If one of the callbacks throws, or returns a rejected promise, you can handle the error with a catch at the end of the chain:

```
imageUploader.uploadFilePromise(req.file.path)
    .then(filename => imageUploader.getExternalUrl(filename))
    .then(publicUrl => console.log(publicUrl))
    .catch(error -> console.log(error));
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply regarding chaining promises with .then, I find it cleaner to not add an indent.

ex.

```
promise  
.then(do something)  
.then(do something else);
```